# Most efficient way to sum contents of an ArrayList by powers of 2 element?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am having a brain fart an can't think of the algorithm to compute the sum of an array by powers of 2 element.

This is definitely wrong, but I can't see where though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    intArray.add(1);
    intArray.add(2);
    intArray.add(3);
    intArray.add(4);
    intArray.add(5);
    intArray.add(6);
    intArray.add(7);
    intArray.add(8);
    intArray.add(9);
    intArray.add(10);

    int total = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < intArray.size(); x += 2*(int)Math.pow(2, x)) {
        total = total + intArray.get(x);
    }
    System.out.println(total); 
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of desired input and output? Try writing out the steps it should perform and working backwards from that to get a loop.

Comment: your for loop is wrong. it should be `for (int x = 0; x < intArray.size(); x++)` x is a counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pow2IndexSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        intArray.add(1);
        intArray.add(2);
        intArray.add(3);
        intArray.add(4);
        intArray.add(5);
        intArray.add(6);
        intArray.add(7);
        intArray.add(8);
        intArray.add(9);
        intArray.add(10);

        int total = 0;

        for (int x = 1; x < intArray.size(); x *= 2) {
            total += intArray.get(x);
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it -- touche.

Comment: @DylonEdwards It happens)